# How to remove part of URI/ Redirecting a non-existent directory to an existing directory without changing the URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 7 URLs that are written:

http://www.example.com/TERMS/file

what I want is:

http://www.example.com/file

Problems are:

- files aren't in my main directory so its a non-existing path, causing error:404 when I try rewriting it normally with mod_rewrite
- I have file extensions turned off using the following:

  ```
  > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond
  > %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php RewriteCond
  > %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
  > RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L]
  ```

which I believe is causing some conflict with the rewrites that I try doing.

If it helps, I also have mod_rewrite also forcing www on the address

I have tried looking for solutions on this site and have tried over 10 different methods, but none have worked for me.

and no, neither

```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/TERMS/(.*) $1/$2
```

nor the

```
> (.+)
```

variation work for me.

Comment: essentially: I want to retain http://www.example.com/file as the address, while showing the page for http://www.example.com/TERMS/file

Comment: @JAL thank you for your input, but unfortunately for some odd reason this made my entire website render without css ... awkward ... and it also made all my images disappear as well ... possibly because I have hotlinking protection too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule **after other rules** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!TERMS/).+)$ /TERMS/$1 [L,NC]
```